# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager

Tags: java, apache-poi, awt

when we migrated from Oracle JDK-8 to Open JDK-11, Apache POI excel generation has issues

tried already `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

````
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)```
````

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: we are using openJDK and cannot go back to oracle JDK

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you are using the docker ['slim images'](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/d4f015a4a99883c6b8691ec6aaf24a74cd02916a/openjdk/README.md#openjdkversion-slim) of openjdk, the image no longer includes the packages 'fontconfig', and 'libfreetype6'.

Check the difference in [docker file](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/2544422915ae09bf77b02f0afaadaad5ba204cef/11/jdk/slim/Dockerfile#L29) of openjdk:11-slim and the [docker file](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/2544422915ae09bf77b02f0afaadaad5ba204cef/8/jdk/Dockerfile#L13) of openjdk:8-slim.

You could either pick another docker image (e.g. `openjdk:11-windowsservercore`), or install the packages yourself in your docker file:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y fontconfig libfreetype6 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This worked perfectly when using the 'tomcat:9-jdk11-openjdk-slim' image.

Comment: In docker file, updated "FROM library/openjdk:8-jdk-slim" to "FROM openjdk:8u232-jdk" fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: What if I have alpine version? libfreetype6 is not present in alpine. I tried freetype instead but it doesn't work..

Comment: @DenB For Alpine, I found no other way than installing libgcc (and I added the optional compatibility packages to atone for my sins) : apk add freetype-dev libgcc libc6-compat gcompat

Comment: To minimize the Docker layer size, you may want to remove the `apt-get update` temporary files once you're done with the `apt-get install` step. You can do that by appending `&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. Also, it makes sense to join commands with `&&` rather than `;`, since you probably want to fail early if anything goes wrong with the update step.

Comment: Needed to add this to a project using `openjdk:8-jre-slim`, and the suggestion here worked. Note: if using a multi-stage docker build, be sure to add this at the correct stage.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying issues is something else

I just created a simple class which does class loading of X11FontManager and when I ran 
it complained

```
unable to link "libfreetype6"
```

once I installed it using

```
apt-get install libfreetype6
```

started throwing could not link "libfontconfig1.so"

```
apt-get install libfontconfig1
```

that fixed the issue

Read this and understood few things 
https://medium.com/azulsystems/using-jlink-to-build-java-runtimes-for-non-modular-applications-9568c5e70ef4

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurs when you use openjdk docker image in **alpine** version for example :

`adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine`.

You need chenge image to full version: `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9`

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-06-23 03:44:37.950  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-7] ReportService   : Template path : /jasper/MgmtSummary.jrxml
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
```

I was getting the above error when I was using docker image `gcr.io/distroless/java-debian10:11`

And this was fixed when I change the image to `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11`